# Pairs of palindromic anagramic dates separated by a palindromic number of days

Tags: code-golf, date, permutations, palindrome

**Definitions:**

A palindrome is a string which reads the same backward or forward (not counting spaces or special characters), such as "madam" or "Sorel Eros". 
A date is said to be a palindrome when its dd-mm-yyyy format is a palindrome (or any other local representation).

Two strings are said to be anagrams when the contain the same characters (modulo a rearrangement), such as "Silent" and "Listen". Two dates are anagrams when their representation (the same as the one chosen for 1.) are anagrams.

**Challenge:**

The challenge is to find all the pairs (a,b) of dates (between 1/1/01 and 12/31/9999) which satisfy the following three conditions :

1. a and b are different
2. a and b are palindromes
3. a and b are anagrams
4. a and b are separated by a number of days which is a palindrome.

**Constraints**

You can choose one of the three date formats :

- yyyy-mm-dd
- dd-mm-yyyy
- mm-dd-yyyy

That means left padding with zeros for days and month (02/02/1999) and a 4 zeros padding for years.

You must respect leap years + every 100 years leap + every 400 years leap such as specified in the [Proleptic Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar)

**Input**
None.

**Output**

Pairs of dates (same format) and the number of days separating them
Display format can be different to the computation format.

31-03-3013 - 13-03-3031 :: 6556

[EDIT]

[Standard loopholes apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)

This is code golf, shortest code wins!

Comment: [Related: list all palindromic prime dates between `0000-01-01` and `99999-12-31`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/153249/52210)

Comment: Are single digit numbers palindromes? if they are, we need to list all palindromic dates too. So, are a and b different dates?

Comment: When are the numbers left-padded with zeros and with how many zeroes?

Comment: Edited to address comments. Yes a and b are different and the numbers are padded (february -> 02, december -> 12 and same for day)

Comment: Haha just checking if both dates are palindromes for the first 50 years times out in TIO for PHP, gonna warm up the `max_execution_time` in preparation

Comment: Why having edited for "no zero padding for years"?, it wasn't asked for and will bother many I think.. can we have the choice on this?

Comment: Are we allowed to check the palindromizes for dates with format `dd-mm-yyyy`, yet still output them as format `yyyy-mm-dd`?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen yes; Computation must be in the same format system, but output can be any format

Answer (score 10):

## Polyglot, 0 bytes

When using the formats `yyyy-mm-dd` or `mm-dd-yyyy`, the list of palindrome dates are:

```
yyyy-mm-dd: [0101-10-10, 0110-01-10, 0111-11-10, 0120-02-10, 0121-12-10, 0130-03-10, 0140-04-10, 0150-05-10, 0160-06-10, 0170-07-10, 0180-08-10, 0190-09-10, 0201-10-20, 0210-01-20, 0211-11-20, 0220-02-20, 0221-12-20, 0230-03-20, 0240-04-20, 0250-05-20, 0260-06-20, 0270-07-20, 0280-08-20, 0290-09-20, 0301-10-30, 0310-01-30, 0311-11-30, 0321-12-30, 0330-03-30, 0340-04-30, 0350-05-30, 0360-06-30, 0370-07-30, 0380-08-30, 0390-09-30, 1001-10-01, 1010-01-01, 1011-11-01, 1020-02-01, 1021-12-01, 1030-03-01, 1040-04-01, 1050-05-01, 1060-06-01, 1070-07-01, 1080-08-01, 1090-09-01, 1101-10-11, 1110-01-11, 1111-11-11, 1120-02-11, 1121-12-11, 1130-03-11, 1140-04-11, 1150-05-11, 1160-06-11, 1170-07-11, 1180-08-11, 1190-09-11, 1201-10-21, 1210-01-21, 1211-11-21, 1220-02-21, 1221-12-21, 1230-03-21, 1240-04-21, 1250-05-21, 1260-06-21, 1270-07-21, 1280-08-21, 1290-09-21, 1301-10-31, 1310-01-31, 1321-12-31, 1330-03-31, 1350-05-31, 1370-07-31, 1380-08-31, 2001-10-02, 2010-01-02, 2011-11-02, 2020-02-02, 2021-12-02, 2030-03-02, 2040-04-02, 2050-05-02, 2060-06-02, 2070-07-02, 2080-08-02, 2090-09-02, 2101-10-12, 2110-01-12, 2111-11-12, 2120-02-12, 2121-12-12, 2130-03-12, 2140-04-12, 2150-05-12, 2160-06-12, 2170-07-12, 2180-08-12, 2190-09-12, 2201-10-22, 2210-01-22, 2211-11-22, 2220-02-22, 2221-12-22, 2230-03-22, 2240-04-22, 2250-05-22, 2260-06-22, 2270-07-22, 2280-08-22, 2290-09-22, 3001-10-03, 3010-01-03, 3011-11-03, 3020-02-03, 3021-12-03, 3030-03-03, 3040-04-03, 3050-05-03, 3060-06-03, 3070-07-03, 3080-08-03, 3090-09-03, 3101-10-13, 3110-01-13, 3111-11-13, 3120-02-13, 3121-12-13, 3130-03-13, 3140-04-13, 3150-05-13, 3160-06-13, 3170-07-13, 3180-08-13, 3190-09-13, 3201-10-23, 3210-01-23, 3211-11-23, 3220-02-23, 3221-12-23, 3230-03-23, 3240-04-23, 3250-05-23, 3260-06-23, 3270-07-23, 3280-08-23, 3290-09-23, 4001-10-04, 4010-01-04, 4011-11-04, 4020-02-04, 4021-12-04, 4030-03-04, 4040-04-04, 4050-05-04, 4060-06-04, 4070-07-04, 4080-08-04, 4090-09-04, 4101-10-14, 4110-01-14, 4111-11-14, 4120-02-14, 4121-12-14, 4130-03-14, 4140-04-14, 4150-05-14, 4160-06-14, 4170-07-14, 4180-08-14, 4190-09-14, 4201-10-24, 4210-01-24, 4211-11-24, 4220-02-24, 4221-12-24, 4230-03-24, 4240-04-24, 4250-05-24, 4260-06-24, 4270-07-24, 4280-08-24, 4290-09-24, 5001-10-05, 5010-01-05, 5011-11-05, 5020-02-05, 5021-12-05, 5030-03-05, 5040-04-05, 5050-05-05, 5060-06-05, 5070-07-05, 5080-08-05, 5090-09-05, 5101-10-15, 5110-01-15, 5111-11-15, 5120-02-15, 5121-12-15, 5130-03-15, 5140-04-15, 5150-05-15, 5160-06-15, 5170-07-15, 5180-08-15, 5190-09-15, 5201-10-25, 5210-01-25, 5211-11-25, 5220-02-25, 5221-12-25, 5230-03-25, 5240-04-25, 5250-05-25, 5260-06-25, 5270-07-25, 5280-08-25, 5290-09-25, 6001-10-06, 6010-01-06, 6011-11-06, 6020-02-06, 6021-12-06, 6030-03-06, 6040-04-06, 6050-05-06, 6060-06-06, 6070-07-06, 6080-08-06, 6090-09-06, 6101-10-16, 6110-01-16, 6111-11-16, 6120-02-16, 6121-12-16, 6130-03-16, 6140-04-16, 6150-05-16, 6160-06-16, 6170-07-16, 6180-08-16, 6190-09-16, 6201-10-26, 6210-01-26, 6211-11-26, 6220-02-26, 6221-12-26, 6230-03-26, 6240-04-26, 6250-05-26, 6260-06-26, 6270-07-26, 6280-08-26, 6290-09-26, 7001-10-07, 7010-01-07, 7011-11-07, 7020-02-07, 7021-12-07, 7030-03-07, 7040-04-07, 7050-05-07, 7060-06-07, 7070-07-07, 7080-08-07, 7090-09-07, 7101-10-17, 7110-01-17, 7111-11-17, 7120-02-17, 7121-12-17, 7130-03-17, 7140-04-17, 7150-05-17, 7160-06-17, 7170-07-17, 7180-08-17, 7190-09-17, 7201-10-27, 7210-01-27, 7211-11-27, 7220-02-27, 7221-12-27, 7230-03-27, 7240-04-27, 7250-05-27, 7260-06-27, 7270-07-27, 7280-08-27, 7290-09-27, 8001-10-08, 8010-01-08, 8011-11-08, 8020-02-08, 8021-12-08, 8030-03-08, 8040-04-08, 8050-05-08, 8060-06-08, 8070-07-08, 8080-08-08, 8090-09-08, 8101-10-18, 8110-01-18, 8111-11-18, 8120-02-18, 8121-12-18, 8130-03-18, 8140-04-18, 8150-05-18, 8160-06-18, 8170-07-18, 8180-08-18, 8190-09-18, 8201-10-28, 8210-01-28, 8211-11-28, 8220-02-28, 8221-12-28, 8230-03-28, 8240-04-28, 8250-05-28, 8260-06-28, 8270-07-28, 8280-08-28, 8290-09-28, 9001-10-09, 9010-01-09, 9011-11-09, 9020-02-09, 9021-12-09, 9030-03-09, 9040-04-09, 9050-05-09, 9060-06-09, 9070-07-09, 9080-08-09, 9090-09-09, 9101-10-19, 9110-01-19, 9111-11-19, 9120-02-19, 9121-12-19, 9130-03-19, 9140-04-19, 9150-05-19, 9160-06-19, 9170-07-19, 9180-08-19, 9190-09-19, 9201-10-29, 9210-01-29, 9211-11-29, 9220-02-29, 9221-12-29, 9230-03-29, 9240-04-29, 9250-05-29, 9260-06-29, 9270-07-29, 9280-08-29, 9290-09-29]
mm-dd-yyyy: [10-10-0101, 01-10-0110, 11-10-0111, 02-10-0120, 12-10-0121, 03-10-0130, 04-10-0140, 05-10-0150, 06-10-0160, 07-10-0170, 08-10-0180, 09-10-0190, 10-20-0201, 01-20-0210, 11-20-0211, 02-20-0220, 12-20-0221, 03-20-0230, 04-20-0240, 05-20-0250, 06-20-0260, 07-20-0270, 08-20-0280, 09-20-0290, 10-30-0301, 01-30-0310, 11-30-0311, 12-30-0321, 03-30-0330, 04-30-0340, 05-30-0350, 06-30-0360, 07-30-0370, 08-30-0380, 09-30-0390, 10-01-1001, 01-01-1010, 11-01-1011, 02-01-1020, 12-01-1021, 03-01-1030, 04-01-1040, 05-01-1050, 06-01-1060, 07-01-1070, 08-01-1080, 09-01-1090, 10-11-1101, 01-11-1110, 11-11-1111, 02-11-1120, 12-11-1121, 03-11-1130, 04-11-1140, 05-11-1150, 06-11-1160, 07-11-1170, 08-11-1180, 09-11-1190, 10-21-1201, 01-21-1210, 11-21-1211, 02-21-1220, 12-21-1221, 03-21-1230, 04-21-1240, 05-21-1250, 06-21-1260, 07-21-1270, 08-21-1280, 09-21-1290, 10-31-1301, 01-31-1310, 12-31-1321, 03-31-1330, 05-31-1350, 07-31-1370, 08-31-1380, 10-02-2001, 01-02-2010, 11-02-2011, 02-02-2020, 12-02-2021, 03-02-2030, 04-02-2040, 05-02-2050, 06-02-2060, 07-02-2070, 08-02-2080, 09-02-2090, 10-12-2101, 01-12-2110, 11-12-2111, 02-12-2120, 12-12-2121, 03-12-2130, 04-12-2140, 05-12-2150, 06-12-2160, 07-12-2170, 08-12-2180, 09-12-2190, 10-22-2201, 01-22-2210, 11-22-2211, 02-22-2220, 12-22-2221, 03-22-2230, 04-22-2240, 05-22-2250, 06-22-2260, 07-22-2270, 08-22-2280, 09-22-2290, 10-03-3001, 01-03-3010, 11-03-3011, 02-03-3020, 12-03-3021, 03-03-3030, 04-03-3040, 05-03-3050, 06-03-3060, 07-03-3070, 08-03-3080, 09-03-3090, 10-13-3101, 01-13-3110, 11-13-3111, 02-13-3120, 12-13-3121, 03-13-3130, 04-13-3140, 05-13-3150, 06-13-3160, 07-13-3170, 08-13-3180, 09-13-3190, 10-23-3201, 01-23-3210, 11-23-3211, 02-23-3220, 12-23-3221, 03-23-3230, 04-23-3240, 05-23-3250, 06-23-3260, 07-23-3270, 08-23-3280, 09-23-3290, 10-04-4001, 01-04-4010, 11-04-4011, 02-04-4020, 12-04-4021, 03-04-4030, 04-04-4040, 05-04-4050, 06-04-4060, 07-04-4070, 08-04-4080, 09-04-4090, 10-14-4101, 01-14-4110, 11-14-4111, 02-14-4120, 12-14-4121, 03-14-4130, 04-14-4140, 05-14-4150, 06-14-4160, 07-14-4170, 08-14-4180, 09-14-4190, 10-24-4201, 01-24-4210, 11-24-4211, 02-24-4220, 12-24-4221, 03-24-4230, 04-24-4240, 05-24-4250, 06-24-4260, 07-24-4270, 08-24-4280, 09-24-4290, 10-05-5001, 01-05-5010, 11-05-5011, 02-05-5020, 12-05-5021, 03-05-5030, 04-05-5040, 05-05-5050, 06-05-5060, 07-05-5070, 08-05-5080, 09-05-5090, 10-15-5101, 01-15-5110, 11-15-5111, 02-15-5120, 12-15-5121, 03-15-5130, 04-15-5140, 05-15-5150, 06-15-5160, 07-15-5170, 08-15-5180, 09-15-5190, 10-25-5201, 01-25-5210, 11-25-5211, 02-25-5220, 12-25-5221, 03-25-5230, 04-25-5240, 05-25-5250, 06-25-5260, 07-25-5270, 08-25-5280, 09-25-5290, 10-06-6001, 01-06-6010, 11-06-6011, 02-06-6020, 12-06-6021, 03-06-6030, 04-06-6040, 05-06-6050, 06-06-6060, 07-06-6070, 08-06-6080, 09-06-6090, 10-16-6101, 01-16-6110, 11-16-6111, 02-16-6120, 12-16-6121, 03-16-6130, 04-16-6140, 05-16-6150, 06-16-6160, 07-16-6170, 08-16-6180, 09-16-6190, 10-26-6201, 01-26-6210, 11-26-6211, 02-26-6220, 12-26-6221, 03-26-6230, 04-26-6240, 05-26-6250, 06-26-6260, 07-26-6270, 08-26-6280, 09-26-6290, 10-07-7001, 01-07-7010, 11-07-7011, 02-07-7020, 12-07-7021, 03-07-7030, 04-07-7040, 05-07-7050, 06-07-7060, 07-07-7070, 08-07-7080, 09-07-7090, 10-17-7101, 01-17-7110, 11-17-7111, 02-17-7120, 12-17-7121, 03-17-7130, 04-17-7140, 05-17-7150, 06-17-7160, 07-17-7170, 08-17-7180, 09-17-7190, 10-27-7201, 01-27-7210, 11-27-7211, 02-27-7220, 12-27-7221, 03-27-7230, 04-27-7240, 05-27-7250, 06-27-7260, 07-27-7270, 08-27-7280, 09-27-7290, 10-08-8001, 01-08-8010, 11-08-8011, 02-08-8020, 12-08-8021, 03-08-8030, 04-08-8040, 05-08-8050, 06-08-8060, 07-08-8070, 08-08-8080, 09-08-8090, 10-18-8101, 01-18-8110, 11-18-8111, 02-18-8120, 12-18-8121, 03-18-8130, 04-18-8140, 05-18-8150, 06-18-8160, 07-18-8170, 08-18-8180, 09-18-8190, 10-28-8201, 01-28-8210, 11-28-8211, 02-28-8220, 12-28-8221, 03-28-8230, 04-28-8240, 05-28-8250, 06-28-8260, 07-28-8270, 08-28-8280, 09-28-8290, 10-09-9001, 01-09-9010, 11-09-9011, 02-09-9020, 12-09-9021, 03-09-9030, 04-09-9040, 05-09-9050, 06-09-9060, 07-09-9070, 08-09-9080, 09-09-9090, 10-19-9101, 01-19-9110, 11-19-9111, 02-19-9120, 12-19-9121, 03-19-9130, 04-19-9140, 05-19-9150, 06-19-9160, 07-19-9170, 08-19-9180, 09-19-9190, 10-29-9201, 01-29-9210, 11-29-9211, 02-29-9220, 12-29-9221, 03-29-9230, 04-29-9240, 05-29-9250, 06-29-9260, 07-29-9270, 08-29-9280, 09-29-9290]
```

All possible date-pairs which are anagrams between one-another are:

```
yyyy-mm-dd: [[0101-10-10,0110-10-01], [0101-10-10,1001-01-10], [0101-10-10,1010-01-01], [0102-10-20,0120-10-02], [0102-10-20,1002-01-20], [0102-10-20,1020-01-02], [0102-10-20,2001-02-10], [0102-10-20,2010-02-01], [0103-10-30,0130-10-03], [0103-10-30,1003-01-30], [0103-10-30,1030-01-03], [0103-10-30,3001-03-10], [0103-10-30,3010-03-01], [0110-10-01,1001-01-10], [0110-10-01,1010-01-01], [0111-10-11,1011-01-11], [0111-10-11,1101-11-10], [0111-10-11,1110-11-01], [0112-10-21,0121-10-12], [0112-10-21,1012-01-21], [0112-10-21,1021-01-12], [0112-10-21,1102-11-20], [0112-10-21,1120-11-02], [0112-10-21,2011-02-11], [0112-10-21,2101-12-10], [0112-10-21,2110-12-01], [0113-10-31,0131-10-13], [0113-10-31,1013-01-31], [0113-10-31,1031-01-13], [0113-10-31,1103-11-30], [0113-10-31,1130-11-03], [0113-10-31,3011-03-11], [0120-10-02,1002-01-20], [0120-10-02,1020-01-02], [0120-10-02,2001-02-10], [0120-10-02,2010-02-01], [0121-10-12,1012-01-21], [0121-10-12,1021-01-12], [0121-10-12,1102-11-20], [0121-10-12,1120-11-02], [0121-10-12,2011-02-11], [0121-10-12,2101-12-10], [0121-10-12,2110-12-01], [0122-10-22,1022-01-22], [0122-10-22,2012-02-21], [0122-10-22,2021-02-12], [0122-10-22,2102-12-20], [0122-10-22,2120-12-02], [0130-10-03,1003-01-30], [0130-10-03,1030-01-03], [0130-10-03,3001-03-10], [0130-10-03,3010-03-01], [0131-10-13,1013-01-31], [0131-10-13,1031-01-13], [0131-10-13,1103-11-30], [0131-10-13,1130-11-03], [0131-10-13,3011-03-11], [0132-10-23,1032-01-23], [0132-10-23,2031-02-13], [0132-10-23,2103-12-30], [0132-10-23,2130-12-03], [0132-10-23,3012-03-21], [0132-10-23,3021-03-12], [0140-10-04,1040-01-04], [0140-10-04,4001-04-10], [0140-10-04,4010-04-01], [0141-10-14,1041-01-14], [0141-10-14,1140-11-04], [0141-10-14,4011-04-11], [0142-10-24,1042-01-24], [0142-10-24,2041-02-14], [0142-10-24,2140-12-04], [0142-10-24,4012-04-21], [0142-10-24,4021-04-12], [0150-10-05,1050-01-05], [0150-10-05,5001-05-10], [0150-10-05,5010-05-01], [0151-10-15,1051-01-15], [0151-10-15,1150-11-05], [0151-10-15,5011-05-11], [0152-10-25,1052-01-25], [0152-10-25,2051-02-15], [0152-10-25,2150-12-05], [0152-10-25,5012-05-21], [0152-10-25,5021-05-12], [0160-10-06,1060-01-06], [0160-10-06,6001-06-10], [0160-10-06,6010-06-01], [0161-10-16,1061-01-16], [0161-10-16,1160-11-06], [0161-10-16,6011-06-11], [0162-10-26,1062-01-26], [0162-10-26,2061-02-16], [0162-10-26,2160-12-06], [0162-10-26,6012-06-21], [0162-10-26,6021-06-12], [0170-10-07,1070-01-07], [0170-10-07,7001-07-10], [0170-10-07,7010-07-01], [0171-10-17,1071-01-17], [0171-10-17,1170-11-07], [0171-10-17,7011-07-11], [0172-10-27,1072-01-27], [0172-10-27,2071-02-17], [0172-10-27,2170-12-07], [0172-10-27,7012-07-21], [0172-10-27,7021-07-12], [0180-10-08,1080-01-08], [0180-10-08,8001-08-10], [0180-10-08,8010-08-01], [0181-10-18,1081-01-18], [0181-10-18,1180-11-08], [0181-10-18,8011-08-11], [0182-10-28,1082-01-28], [0182-10-28,2081-02-18], [0182-10-28,2180-12-08], [0182-10-28,8012-08-21], [0182-10-28,8021-08-12], [0190-10-09,1090-01-09], [0190-10-09,9001-09-10], [0190-10-09,9010-09-01], [0191-10-19,1091-01-19], [0191-10-19,1190-11-09], [0191-10-19,9011-09-11], [0192-10-29,1092-01-29], [0192-10-29,2091-02-19], [0192-10-29,2190-12-09], [0192-10-29,9012-09-21], [0192-10-29,9021-09-12], [1001-01-10,1010-01-01], [1002-01-20,1020-01-02], [1002-01-20,2001-02-10], [1002-01-20,2010-02-01], [1003-01-30,1030-01-03], [1003-01-30,3001-03-10], [1003-01-30,3010-03-01], [1011-01-11,1101-11-10], [1011-01-11,1110-11-01], [1012-01-21,1021-01-12], [1012-01-21,1102-11-20], [1012-01-21,1120-11-02], [1012-01-21,2011-02-11], [1012-01-21,2101-12-10], [1012-01-21,2110-12-01], [1013-01-31,1031-01-13], [1013-01-31,1103-11-30], [1013-01-31,1130-11-03], [1013-01-31,3011-03-11], [1020-01-02,2001-02-10], [1020-01-02,2010-02-01], [1021-01-12,1102-11-20], [1021-01-12,1120-11-02], [1021-01-12,2011-02-11], [1021-01-12,2101-12-10], [1021-01-12,2110-12-01], [1022-01-22,2012-02-21], [1022-01-22,2021-02-12], [1022-01-22,2102-12-20], [1022-01-22,2120-12-02], [1030-01-03,3001-03-10], [1030-01-03,3010-03-01], [1031-01-13,1103-11-30], [1031-01-13,1130-11-03], [1031-01-13,3011-03-11], [1032-01-23,2031-02-13], [1032-01-23,2103-12-30], [1032-01-23,2130-12-03], [1032-01-23,3012-03-21], [1032-01-23,3021-03-12], [1040-01-04,4001-04-10], [1040-01-04,4010-04-01], [1041-01-14,1140-11-04], [1041-01-14,4011-04-11], [1042-01-24,2041-02-14], [1042-01-24,2140-12-04], [1042-01-24,4012-04-21], [1042-01-24,4021-04-12], [1050-01-05,5001-05-10], [1050-01-05,5010-05-01], [1051-01-15,1150-11-05], [1051-01-15,5011-05-11], [1052-01-25,2051-02-15], [1052-01-25,2150-12-05], [1052-01-25,5012-05-21], [1052-01-25,5021-05-12], [1060-01-06,6001-06-10], [1060-01-06,6010-06-01], [1061-01-16,1160-11-06], [1061-01-16,6011-06-11], [1062-01-26,2061-02-16], [1062-01-26,2160-12-06], [1062-01-26,6012-06-21], [1062-01-26,6021-06-12], [1070-01-07,7001-07-10], [1070-01-07,7010-07-01], [1071-01-17,1170-11-07], [1071-01-17,7011-07-11], [1072-01-27,2071-02-17], [1072-01-27,2170-12-07], [1072-01-27,7012-07-21], [1072-01-27,7021-07-12], [1080-01-08,8001-08-10], [1080-01-08,8010-08-01], [1081-01-18,1180-11-08], [1081-01-18,8011-08-11], [1082-01-28,2081-02-18], [1082-01-28,2180-12-08], [1082-01-28,8012-08-21], [1082-01-28,8021-08-12], [1090-01-09,9001-09-10], [1090-01-09,9010-09-01], [1091-01-19,1190-11-09], [1091-01-19,9011-09-11], [1092-01-29,2091-02-19], [1092-01-29,2190-12-09], [1092-01-29,9012-09-21], [1092-01-29,9021-09-12], [1101-11-10,1110-11-01], [1102-11-20,1120-11-02], [1102-11-20,2011-02-11], [1102-11-20,2101-12-10], [1102-11-20,2110-12-01], [1103-11-30,1130-11-03], [1103-11-30,3011-03-11], [1112-11-21,1121-11-12], [1112-11-21,2111-12-11], [1120-11-02,2011-02-11], [1120-11-02,2101-12-10], [1120-11-02,2110-12-01], [1121-11-12,2111-12-11], [1122-11-22,2112-12-21], [1122-11-22,2121-12-12], [1130-11-03,3011-03-11], [1132-11-23,2113-12-31], [1132-11-23,2131-12-13], [1140-11-04,4011-04-11], [1142-11-24,2141-12-14], [1150-11-05,5011-05-11], [1152-11-25,2151-12-15], [1160-11-06,6011-06-11], [1162-11-26,2161-12-16], [1170-11-07,7011-07-11], [1172-11-27,2171-12-17], [1180-11-08,8011-08-11], [1182-11-28,2181-12-18], [1190-11-09,9011-09-11], [1192-11-29,2191-12-19], [2001-02-10,2010-02-01], [2002-02-20,2020-02-02], [2011-02-11,2101-12-10], [2011-02-11,2110-12-01], [2012-02-21,2021-02-12], [2012-02-21,2102-12-20], [2012-02-21,2120-12-02], [2021-02-12,2102-12-20], [2021-02-12,2120-12-02], [2030-02-03,3002-03-20], [2030-02-03,3020-03-02], [2031-02-13,2103-12-30], [2031-02-13,2130-12-03], [2031-02-13,3012-03-21], [2031-02-13,3021-03-12], [2032-02-23,3022-03-22], [2040-02-04,4002-04-20], [2040-02-04,4020-04-02], [2041-02-14,2140-12-04], [2041-02-14,4012-04-21], [2041-02-14,4021-04-12], [2042-02-24,4022-04-22], [2050-02-05,5002-05-20], [2050-02-05,5020-05-02], [2051-02-15,2150-12-05], [2051-02-15,5012-05-21], [2051-02-15,5021-05-12], [2052-02-25,5022-05-22], [2060-02-06,6002-06-20], [2060-02-06,6020-06-02], [2061-02-16,2160-12-06], [2061-02-16,6012-06-21], [2061-02-16,6021-06-12], [2062-02-26,6022-06-22], [2070-02-07,7002-07-20], [2070-02-07,7020-07-02], [2071-02-17,2170-12-07], [2071-02-17,7012-07-21], [2071-02-17,7021-07-12], [2072-02-27,7022-07-22], [2080-02-08,8002-08-20], [2080-02-08,8020-08-02], [2081-02-18,2180-12-08], [2081-02-18,8012-08-21], [2081-02-18,8021-08-12], [2082-02-28,8022-08-22], [2090-02-09,9002-09-20], [2090-02-09,9020-09-02], [2091-02-19,2190-12-09], [2091-02-19,9012-09-21], [2091-02-19,9021-09-12], [2092-02-29,9022-09-22], [2101-12-10,2110-12-01], [2102-12-20,2120-12-02], [2103-12-30,2130-12-03], [2103-12-30,3012-03-21], [2103-12-30,3021-03-12], [2112-12-21,2121-12-12], [2113-12-31,2131-12-13], [2130-12-03,3012-03-21], [2130-12-03,3021-03-12], [2140-12-04,4012-04-21], [2140-12-04,4021-04-12], [2150-12-05,5012-05-21], [2150-12-05,5021-05-12], [2160-12-06,6012-06-21], [2160-12-06,6021-06-12], [2170-12-07,7012-07-21], [2170-12-07,7021-07-12], [2180-12-08,8012-08-21], [2180-12-08,8021-08-12], [2190-12-09,9012-09-21], [2190-12-09,9021-09-12], [3001-03-10,3010-03-01], [3002-03-20,3020-03-02], [3003-03-30,3030-03-03], [3012-03-21,3021-03-12], [3013-03-31,3031-03-13], [3040-03-04,4003-04-30], [3040-03-04,4030-04-03], [3041-03-14,4031-04-13], [3042-03-24,4032-04-23], [3050-03-05,5003-05-30], [3050-03-05,5030-05-03], [3051-03-15,5013-05-31], [3051-03-15,5031-05-13], [3052-03-25,5032-05-23], [3060-03-06,6003-06-30], [3060-03-06,6030-06-03], [3061-03-16,6031-06-13], [3062-03-26,6032-06-23], [3070-03-07,7003-07-30], [3070-03-07,7030-07-03], [3071-03-17,7013-07-31], [3071-03-17,7031-07-13], [3072-03-27,7032-07-23], [3080-03-08,8003-08-30], [3080-03-08,8030-08-03], [3081-03-18,8013-08-31], [3081-03-18,8031-08-13], [3082-03-28,8032-08-23], [3090-03-09,9003-09-30], [3090-03-09,9030-09-03], [3091-03-19,9031-09-13], [3092-03-29,9032-09-23], [4001-04-10,4010-04-01], [4002-04-20,4020-04-02], [4003-04-30,4030-04-03], [4012-04-21,4021-04-12], [4050-04-05,5040-05-04], [4051-04-15,5041-05-14], [4052-04-25,5042-05-24], [4060-04-06,6040-06-04], [4061-04-16,6041-06-14], [4062-04-26,6042-06-24], [4070-04-07,7040-07-04], [4071-04-17,7041-07-14], [4072-04-27,7042-07-24], [4080-04-08,8040-08-04], [4081-04-18,8041-08-14], [4082-04-28,8042-08-24], [4090-04-09,9040-09-04], [4091-04-19,9041-09-14], [4092-04-29,9042-09-24], [5001-05-10,5010-05-01], [5002-05-20,5020-05-02], [5003-05-30,5030-05-03], [5012-05-21,5021-05-12], [5013-05-31,5031-05-13], [5060-05-06,6050-06-05], [5061-05-16,6051-06-15], [5062-05-26,6052-06-25], [5070-05-07,7050-07-05], [5071-05-17,7051-07-15], [5072-05-27,7052-07-25], [5080-05-08,8050-08-05], [5081-05-18,8051-08-15], [5082-05-28,8052-08-25], [5090-05-09,9050-09-05], [5091-05-19,9051-09-15], [5092-05-29,9052-09-25], [6001-06-10,6010-06-01], [6002-06-20,6020-06-02], [6003-06-30,6030-06-03], [6012-06-21,6021-06-12], [6070-06-07,7060-07-06], [6071-06-17,7061-07-16], [6072-06-27,7062-07-26], [6080-06-08,8060-08-06], [6081-06-18,8061-08-16], [6082-06-28,8062-08-26], [6090-06-09,9060-09-06], [6091-06-19,9061-09-16], [6092-06-29,9062-09-26], [7001-07-10,7010-07-01], [7002-07-20,7020-07-02], [7003-07-30,7030-07-03], [7012-07-21,7021-07-12], [7013-07-31,7031-07-13], [7080-07-08,8070-08-07], [7081-07-18,8071-08-17], [7082-07-28,8072-08-27], [7090-07-09,9070-09-07], [7091-07-19,9071-09-17], [7092-07-29,9072-09-27], [8001-08-10,8010-08-01], [8002-08-20,8020-08-02], [8003-08-30,8030-08-03], [8012-08-21,8021-08-12], [8013-08-31,8031-08-13], [8090-08-09,9080-09-08], [8091-08-19,9081-09-18], [8092-08-29,9082-09-28], [9001-09-10,9010-09-01], [9002-09-20,9020-09-02], [9003-09-30,9030-09-03], [9012-09-21,9021-09-12]]
mm-dd-yyyy: [[10-10-0101,01-10-0110], [10-10-0101,10-01-1001], [10-10-0101,01-01-1010], [01-10-0110,10-01-1001], [01-10-0110,01-01-1010], [11-10-0111,11-01-1011], [11-10-0111,10-11-1101], [11-10-0111,01-11-1110], [02-10-0120,10-20-0201], [02-10-0120,01-20-0210], [02-10-0120,02-01-1020], [02-10-0120,10-02-2001], [02-10-0120,01-02-2010], [12-10-0121,11-20-0211], [12-10-0121,12-01-1021], [12-10-0121,02-11-1120], [12-10-0121,10-21-1201], [12-10-0121,01-21-1210], [12-10-0121,11-02-2011], [12-10-0121,10-12-2101], [12-10-0121,01-12-2110], [03-10-0130,10-30-0301], [03-10-0130,01-30-0310], [03-10-0130,03-01-1030], [03-10-0130,10-03-3001], [03-10-0130,01-03-3010], [04-10-0140,04-01-1040], [04-10-0140,10-04-4001], [04-10-0140,01-04-4010], [05-10-0150,05-01-1050], [05-10-0150,10-05-5001], [05-10-0150,01-05-5010], [06-10-0160,06-01-1060], [06-10-0160,10-06-6001], [06-10-0160,01-06-6010], [07-10-0170,07-01-1070], [07-10-0170,10-07-7001], [07-10-0170,01-07-7010], [08-10-0180,08-01-1080], [08-10-0180,10-08-8001], [08-10-0180,01-08-8010], [09-10-0190,09-01-1090], [09-10-0190,10-09-9001], [09-10-0190,01-09-9010], [10-20-0201,01-20-0210], [10-20-0201,02-01-1020], [10-20-0201,10-02-2001], [10-20-0201,01-02-2010], [01-20-0210,02-01-1020], [01-20-0210,10-02-2001], [01-20-0210,01-02-2010], [11-20-0211,12-01-1021], [11-20-0211,02-11-1120], [11-20-0211,10-21-1201], [11-20-0211,01-21-1210], [11-20-0211,11-02-2011], [11-20-0211,10-12-2101], [11-20-0211,01-12-2110], [02-20-0220,02-02-2020], [12-20-0221,02-21-1220], [12-20-0221,12-02-2021], [12-20-0221,02-12-2120], [12-20-0221,10-22-2201], [12-20-0221,01-22-2210], [03-20-0230,03-02-2030], [03-20-0230,02-03-3020], [04-20-0240,04-02-2040], [04-20-0240,02-04-4020], [05-20-0250,05-02-2050], [05-20-0250,02-05-5020], [06-20-0260,06-02-2060], [06-20-0260,02-06-6020], [07-20-0270,07-02-2070], [07-20-0270,02-07-7020], [08-20-0280,08-02-2080], [08-20-0280,02-08-8020], [09-20-0290,09-02-2090], [09-20-0290,02-09-9020], [10-30-0301,01-30-0310], [10-30-0301,03-01-1030], [10-30-0301,10-03-3001], [10-30-0301,01-03-3010], [01-30-0310,03-01-1030], [01-30-0310,10-03-3001], [01-30-0310,01-03-3010], [11-30-0311,03-11-1130], [11-30-0311,10-31-1301], [11-30-0311,01-31-1310], [11-30-0311,11-03-3011], [11-30-0311,10-13-3101], [11-30-0311,01-13-3110], [12-30-0321,03-21-1230], [12-30-0321,03-12-2130], [12-30-0321,12-03-3021], [12-30-0321,02-13-3120], [12-30-0321,10-23-3201], [12-30-0321,01-23-3210], [03-30-0330,03-03-3030], [04-30-0340,04-03-3040], [04-30-0340,03-04-4030], [05-30-0350,05-03-3050], [05-30-0350,03-05-5030], [06-30-0360,06-03-3060], [06-30-0360,03-06-6030], [07-30-0370,07-03-3070], [07-30-0370,03-07-7030], [08-30-0380,08-03-3080], [08-30-0380,03-08-8030], [09-30-0390,09-03-3090], [09-30-0390,03-09-9030], [10-01-1001,01-01-1010], [11-01-1011,10-11-1101], [11-01-1011,01-11-1110], [02-01-1020,10-02-2001], [02-01-1020,01-02-2010], [12-01-1021,02-11-1120], [12-01-1021,10-21-1201], [12-01-1021,01-21-1210], [12-01-1021,11-02-2011], [12-01-1021,10-12-2101], [12-01-1021,01-12-2110], [03-01-1030,10-03-3001], [03-01-1030,01-03-3010], [04-01-1040,10-04-4001], [04-01-1040,01-04-4010], [05-01-1050,10-05-5001], [05-01-1050,01-05-5010], [06-01-1060,10-06-6001], [06-01-1060,01-06-6010], [07-01-1070,10-07-7001], [07-01-1070,01-07-7010], [08-01-1080,10-08-8001], [08-01-1080,01-08-8010], [09-01-1090,10-09-9001], [09-01-1090,01-09-9010], [10-11-1101,01-11-1110], [02-11-1120,10-21-1201], [02-11-1120,01-21-1210], [02-11-1120,11-02-2011], [02-11-1120,10-12-2101], [02-11-1120,01-12-2110], [12-11-1121,11-21-1211], [12-11-1121,11-12-2111], [03-11-1130,10-31-1301], [03-11-1130,01-31-1310], [03-11-1130,11-03-3011], [03-11-1130,10-13-3101], [03-11-1130,01-13-3110], [04-11-1140,11-04-4011], [04-11-1140,10-14-4101], [04-11-1140,01-14-4110], [05-11-1150,11-05-5011], [05-11-1150,10-15-5101], [05-11-1150,01-15-5110], [06-11-1160,11-06-6011], [06-11-1160,10-16-6101], [06-11-1160,01-16-6110], [07-11-1170,11-07-7011], [07-11-1170,10-17-7101], [07-11-1170,01-17-7110], [08-11-1180,11-08-8011], [08-11-1180,10-18-8101], [08-11-1180,01-18-8110], [09-11-1190,11-09-9011], [09-11-1190,10-19-9101], [09-11-1190,01-19-9110], [10-21-1201,01-21-1210], [10-21-1201,11-02-2011], [10-21-1201,10-12-2101], [10-21-1201,01-12-2110], [01-21-1210,11-02-2011], [01-21-1210,10-12-2101], [01-21-1210,01-12-2110], [11-21-1211,11-12-2111], [02-21-1220,12-02-2021], [02-21-1220,02-12-2120], [02-21-1220,10-22-2201], [02-21-1220,01-22-2210], [12-21-1221,12-12-2121], [12-21-1221,11-22-2211], [03-21-1230,03-12-2130], [03-21-1230,12-03-3021], [03-21-1230,02-13-3120], [03-21-1230,10-23-3201], [03-21-1230,01-23-3210], [04-21-1240,04-12-2140], [04-21-1240,12-04-4021], [04-21-1240,02-14-4120], [04-21-1240,10-24-4201], [04-21-1240,01-24-4210], [05-21-1250,05-12-2150], [05-21-1250,12-05-5021], [05-21-1250,02-15-5120], [05-21-1250,10-25-5201], [05-21-1250,01-25-5210], [06-21-1260,06-12-2160], [06-21-1260,12-06-6021], [06-21-1260,02-16-6120], [06-21-1260,10-26-6201], [06-21-1260,01-26-6210], [07-21-1270,07-12-2170], [07-21-1270,12-07-7021], [07-21-1270,02-17-7120], [07-21-1270,10-27-7201], [07-21-1270,01-27-7210], [08-21-1280,08-12-2180], [08-21-1280,12-08-8021], [08-21-1280,02-18-8120], [08-21-1280,10-28-8201], [08-21-1280,01-28-8210], [09-21-1290,09-12-2190], [09-21-1290,12-09-9021], [09-21-1290,02-19-9120], [09-21-1290,10-29-9201], [09-21-1290,01-29-9210], [10-31-1301,01-31-1310], [10-31-1301,11-03-3011], [10-31-1301,10-13-3101], [10-31-1301,01-13-3110], [01-31-1310,11-03-3011], [01-31-1310,10-13-3101], [01-31-1310,01-13-3110], [12-31-1321,12-13-3121], [12-31-1321,11-23-3211], [03-31-1330,03-13-3130], [05-31-1350,05-13-3150], [05-31-1350,03-15-5130], [07-31-1370,07-13-3170], [07-31-1370,03-17-7130], [08-31-1380,08-13-3180], [08-31-1380,03-18-8130], [10-02-2001,01-02-2010], [11-02-2011,10-12-2101], [11-02-2011,01-12-2110], [12-02-2021,02-12-2120], [12-02-2021,10-22-2201], [12-02-2021,01-22-2210], [03-02-2030,02-03-3020], [04-02-2040,02-04-4020], [05-02-2050,02-05-5020], [06-02-2060,02-06-6020], [07-02-2070,02-07-7020], [08-02-2080,02-08-8020], [09-02-2090,02-09-9020], [10-12-2101,01-12-2110], [02-12-2120,10-22-2201], [02-12-2120,01-22-2210], [12-12-2121,11-22-2211], [03-12-2130,12-03-3021], [03-12-2130,02-13-3120], [03-12-2130,10-23-3201], [03-12-2130,01-23-3210], [04-12-2140,12-04-4021], [04-12-2140,02-14-4120], [04-12-2140,10-24-4201], [04-12-2140,01-24-4210], [05-12-2150,12-05-5021], [05-12-2150,02-15-5120], [05-12-2150,10-25-5201], [05-12-2150,01-25-5210], [06-12-2160,12-06-6021], [06-12-2160,02-16-6120], [06-12-2160,10-26-6201], [06-12-2160,01-26-6210], [07-12-2170,12-07-7021], [07-12-2170,02-17-7120], [07-12-2170,10-27-7201], [07-12-2170,01-27-7210], [08-12-2180,12-08-8021], [08-12-2180,02-18-8120], [08-12-2180,10-28-8201], [08-12-2180,01-28-8210], [09-12-2190,12-09-9021], [09-12-2190,02-19-9120], [09-12-2190,10-29-9201], [09-12-2190,01-29-9210], [10-22-2201,01-22-2210], [03-22-2230,02-23-3220], [04-22-2240,02-24-4220], [05-22-2250,02-25-5220], [06-22-2260,02-26-6220], [07-22-2270,02-27-7220], [08-22-2280,02-28-8220], [09-22-2290,02-29-9220], [10-03-3001,01-03-3010], [11-03-3011,10-13-3101], [11-03-3011,01-13-3110], [12-03-3021,02-13-3120], [12-03-3021,10-23-3201], [12-03-3021,01-23-3210], [04-03-3040,03-04-4030], [05-03-3050,03-05-5030], [06-03-3060,03-06-6030], [07-03-3070,03-07-7030], [08-03-3080,03-08-8030], [09-03-3090,03-09-9030], [10-13-3101,01-13-3110], [02-13-3120,10-23-3201], [02-13-3120,01-23-3210], [12-13-3121,11-23-3211], [04-13-3140,03-14-4130], [05-13-3150,03-15-5130], [06-13-3160,03-16-6130], [07-13-3170,03-17-7130], [08-13-3180,03-18-8130], [09-13-3190,03-19-9130], [10-23-3201,01-23-3210], [04-23-3240,03-24-4230], [05-23-3250,03-25-5230], [06-23-3260,03-26-6230], [07-23-3270,03-27-7230], [08-23-3280,03-28-8230], [09-23-3290,03-29-9230], [10-04-4001,01-04-4010], [11-04-4011,10-14-4101], [11-04-4011,01-14-4110], [12-04-4021,02-14-4120], [12-04-4021,10-24-4201], [12-04-4021,01-24-4210], [05-04-4050,04-05-5040], [06-04-4060,04-06-6040], [07-04-4070,04-07-7040], [08-04-4080,04-08-8040], [09-04-4090,04-09-9040], [10-14-4101,01-14-4110], [02-14-4120,10-24-4201], [02-14-4120,01-24-4210], [12-14-4121,11-24-4211], [05-14-4150,04-15-5140], [06-14-4160,04-16-6140], [07-14-4170,04-17-7140], [08-14-4180,04-18-8140], [09-14-4190,04-19-9140], [10-24-4201,01-24-4210], [05-24-4250,04-25-5240], [06-24-4260,04-26-6240], [07-24-4270,04-27-7240], [08-24-4280,04-28-8240], [09-24-4290,04-29-9240], [10-05-5001,01-05-5010], [11-05-5011,10-15-5101], [11-05-5011,01-15-5110], [12-05-5021,02-15-5120], [12-05-5021,10-25-5201], [12-05-5021,01-25-5210], [06-05-5060,05-06-6050], [07-05-5070,05-07-7050], [08-05-5080,05-08-8050], [09-05-5090,05-09-9050], [10-15-5101,01-15-5110], [02-15-5120,10-25-5201], [02-15-5120,01-25-5210], [12-15-5121,11-25-5211], [06-15-5160,05-16-6150], [07-15-5170,05-17-7150], [08-15-5180,05-18-8150], [09-15-5190,05-19-9150], [10-25-5201,01-25-5210], [06-25-5260,05-26-6250], [07-25-5270,05-27-7250], [08-25-5280,05-28-8250], [09-25-5290,05-29-9250], [10-06-6001,01-06-6010], [11-06-6011,10-16-6101], [11-06-6011,01-16-6110], [12-06-6021,02-16-6120], [12-06-6021,10-26-6201], [12-06-6021,01-26-6210], [07-06-6070,06-07-7060], [08-06-6080,06-08-8060], [09-06-6090,06-09-9060], [10-16-6101,01-16-6110], [02-16-6120,10-26-6201], [02-16-6120,01-26-6210], [12-16-6121,11-26-6211], [07-16-6170,06-17-7160], [08-16-6180,06-18-8160], [09-16-6190,06-19-9160], [10-26-6201,01-26-6210], [07-26-6270,06-27-7260], [08-26-6280,06-28-8260], [09-26-6290,06-29-9260], [10-07-7001,01-07-7010], [11-07-7011,10-17-7101], [11-07-7011,01-17-7110], [12-07-7021,02-17-7120], [12-07-7021,10-27-7201], [12-07-7021,01-27-7210], [08-07-7080,07-08-8070], [09-07-7090,07-09-9070], [10-17-7101,01-17-7110], [02-17-7120,10-27-7201], [02-17-7120,01-27-7210], [12-17-7121,11-27-7211], [08-17-7180,07-18-8170], [09-17-7190,07-19-9170], [10-27-7201,01-27-7210], [08-27-7280,07-28-8270], [09-27-7290,07-29-9270], [10-08-8001,01-08-8010], [11-08-8011,10-18-8101], [11-08-8011,01-18-8110], [12-08-8021,02-18-8120], [12-08-8021,10-28-8201], [12-08-8021,01-28-8210], [09-08-8090,08-09-9080], [10-18-8101,01-18-8110], [02-18-8120,10-28-8201], [02-18-8120,01-28-8210], [12-18-8121,11-28-8211], [09-18-8190,08-19-9180], [10-28-8201,01-28-8210], [09-28-8290,08-29-9280], [10-09-9001,01-09-9010], [11-09-9011,10-19-9101], [11-09-9011,01-19-9110], [12-09-9021,02-19-9120], [12-09-9021,10-29-9201], [12-09-9021,01-29-9210], [10-19-9101,01-19-9110], [02-19-9120,10-29-9201], [02-19-9120,01-29-9210], [12-19-9121,11-29-9211], [10-29-9201,01-29-9210]]
```

The differences in days of those pairs are:

```
yyyy-mm-dd: [3278, 328445, 331723, 6557, 328445, 335001, 693344, 696622, 9835, 328445, 338280, 1058239, 1061517, 325167, 328445, 328445, 361620, 364898, 3278, 328444, 331723, 361619, 368176, 693343, 726517, 729795, 6556, 328445, 335001, 361619, 371454, 1058238, 321888, 328444, 686787, 690065, 325166, 328445, 358341, 364898, 690065, 723239, 726517, 328445, 690065, 693344, 723239, 729796, 318610, 328445, 1048404, 1051682, 321889, 328445, 355063, 364898, 1051682, 328444, 693343, 719960, 729795, 1051682, 1054960, 328444, 1410024, 1413302, 328445, 364898, 1413302, 328445, 693344, 729796, 1413303, 1416581, 328445, 1771643, 1774921, 328445, 364898, 1774921, 328444, 693343, 729795, 1774921, 1778199, 328444, 2133263, 2136541, 328445, 364898, 2136541, 328445, 693344, 729796, 2136542, 2139820, 328445, 2494882, 2498160, 328445, 364898, 2498160, 328444, 693343, 729795, 2498160, 2501438, 328444, 2856502, 2859780, 328445, 364898, 2859780, 328445, 693344, 729796, 2859781, 2863059, 328445, 3218122, 3221400, 328445, 364898, 3221400, 328444, 693343, 729795, 3221400, 3224678, 3278, 6556, 364899, 368177, 9835, 729794, 733072, 33175, 36453, 3279, 33175, 39732, 364899, 398073, 401351, 6556, 33174, 43009, 729793, 358343, 361621, 29896, 36453, 361620, 394794, 398072, 361620, 364899, 394794, 401351, 719959, 723237, 26618, 36453, 723237, 364899, 391516, 401351, 723238, 726516, 1081580, 1084858, 36453, 1084857, 364899, 401351, 1084858, 1088136, 1443198, 1446476, 36453, 1446476, 364899, 401351, 1446477, 1449755, 1804819, 1808097, 36453, 1808096, 364899, 401351, 1808097, 1811375, 2166437, 2169715, 36453, 2169715, 364899, 401351, 2169716, 2172994, 2528058, 2531336, 36453, 2531335, 364899, 401351, 2531336, 2534614, 2889677, 2892955, 36453, 2892955, 364899, 401351, 2892956, 2896234, 3278, 6557, 331724, 364898, 368176, 9835, 696619, 3278, 364897, 325167, 358341, 361619, 361619, 361620, 364898, 686784, 358341, 364897, 1048404, 364898, 1410023, 364897, 1771643, 364898, 2133262, 364897, 2494882, 364898, 2856502, 364897, 3278, 6556, 33174, 36452, 3279, 33174, 39731, 29895, 36452, 355060, 361617, 26617, 36452, 358339, 361617, 361617, 716681, 723238, 36452, 719959, 723237, 723237, 1078299, 1084856, 36452, 1081578, 1084856, 1084856, 1439920, 1446477, 36452, 1443198, 1446476, 1446476, 1801538, 1808095, 36452, 1804817, 1808095, 1808095, 2163159, 2169716, 36452, 2166437, 2169715, 2169715, 2524778, 2531335, 36452, 2528057, 2531335, 2531335, 3278, 6557, 9835, 331722, 335000, 3278, 6556, 321887, 325165, 683507, 686785, 1045126, 1048404, 1406746, 1410024, 1768365, 1771643, 2129985, 2133263, 2491605, 2494883, 3278, 6557, 9835, 3278, 6556, 351785, 361620, 361620, 361621, 713404, 723239, 716683, 723239, 723239, 1075024, 1084859, 1084859, 1084860, 1436643, 1446478, 1439922, 1446478, 1446478, 1798263, 1808098, 1801542, 1808098, 1808099, 2159883, 2169718, 2169718, 2169718, 3278, 6557, 9835, 3278, 361619, 361619, 361618, 723239, 723239, 723239, 1084858, 1084858, 1084857, 1446478, 1446478, 1446478, 1808098, 1808098, 1808097, 3278, 6557, 9835, 3278, 6556, 361620, 361620, 361621, 723239, 723239, 723239, 1084859, 1084859, 1084860, 1446479, 1446479, 1446479, 3278, 6557, 9835, 3278, 361619, 361619, 361618, 723239, 723239, 723239, 1084859, 1084859, 1084858, 3278, 6557, 9835, 3278, 6556, 361620, 361620, 361621, 723240, 723240, 723240, 3278, 6557, 9835, 3278, 6556, 361620, 361620, 361619, 3278, 6557, 9835, 3278]
mm-dd-yyyy: [3014, 328709, 331723, 325695, 328709, 328709, 361560, 364574, 29837, 32851, 328709, 687256, 690270, 32851, 328709, 364574, 394412, 397426, 690270, 723121, 726135, 62690, 65704, 328709, 1048818, 1051832, 328709, 1410378, 1413392, 328709, 1771939, 1774953, 328709, 2133499, 2136513, 328709, 2495060, 2498074, 328709, 2856620, 2859634, 328709, 3218180, 3221194, 3014, 298872, 657419, 660433, 295858, 654405, 657419, 295858, 331723, 361561, 364575, 657419, 690270, 693284, 657419, 364575, 657419, 693284, 723121, 726135, 657419, 1018981, 657419, 1380541, 657419, 1742102, 657419, 2103662, 657419, 2465223, 657419, 2826783, 657419, 3188343, 3014, 266019, 986128, 989142, 263005, 983114, 986128, 298870, 361561, 364575, 986128, 1018979, 1021993, 331722, 660431, 986128, 1021993, 1051831, 1054845, 986128, 986128, 1347688, 986128, 1709249, 986128, 2070809, 986128, 2432370, 986128, 2793930, 986128, 3155490, 3014, 32851, 35865, 358547, 361561, 35865, 65703, 68717, 361561, 394412, 397426, 720109, 723123, 1081669, 1084683, 1443230, 1446244, 1804790, 1807804, 2166351, 2169365, 2527911, 2530925, 2889471, 2892485, 3014, 29838, 32852, 325696, 358547, 361561, 32852, 361561, 62691, 65705, 687258, 720109, 723123, 1048818, 1081669, 1084683, 1410379, 1443230, 1446244, 1771939, 1804790, 1807804, 2133500, 2166351, 2169365, 2495060, 2527911, 2530925, 2856620, 2889471, 2892485, 3014, 295858, 328709, 331723, 292844, 325695, 328709, 328709, 292844, 328709, 358546, 361560, 328709, 361560, 328709, 654406, 690271, 720109, 723123, 328709, 1015966, 1051831, 1081668, 1084682, 328709, 1377527, 1413392, 1443230, 1446244, 328709, 1739087, 1774952, 1804789, 1807803, 328709, 2100648, 2136513, 2166351, 2169365, 328709, 2462208, 2498073, 2527910, 2530924, 328709, 2823768, 2859633, 2889471, 2892485, 3014, 624567, 657418, 660432, 621553, 654404, 657418, 657418, 690270, 657418, 657418, 1380539, 657418, 2103660, 657418, 2465220, 3014, 32851, 35865, 35865, 65702, 68716, 361562, 723122, 1084683, 1446243, 1807804, 2169364, 2530924, 3014, 29837, 32851, 32851, 325697, 361562, 391400, 394414, 687257, 723122, 752959, 755973, 1048818, 1084683, 1114521, 1117535, 1410378, 1446243, 1476080, 1479094, 1771939, 1807804, 1837642, 1840656, 2133499, 2169364, 2199201, 2202215, 2495059, 2530924, 2560762, 2563776, 3014, 361563, 723122, 1084684, 1446243, 1807805, 2169364, 2530925, 3014, 32851, 35865, 35865, 65703, 68717, 361560, 723121, 1084681, 1446242, 1807802, 2169362, 3014, 29838, 32852, 32852, 361560, 723121, 1084681, 1446242, 1807802, 2169362, 3014, 361559, 723121, 1084680, 1446242, 1807801, 2169362, 3014, 32851, 35865, 35865, 65702, 68716, 361561, 723121, 1084682, 1446242, 1807802, 3014, 29837, 32851, 32851, 361561, 723121, 1084682, 1446242, 1807802, 3014, 361562, 723121, 1084683, 1446242, 1807803, 3014, 32851, 35865, 35865, 65703, 68717, 361560, 723121, 1084681, 1446241, 3014, 29838, 32852, 32852, 361560, 723121, 1084681, 1446241, 3014, 361559, 723121, 1084680, 1446241, 3014, 32851, 35865, 35865, 65702, 68716, 361561, 723121, 1084681, 3014, 29837, 32851, 32851, 361561, 723121, 1084681, 3014, 361562, 723121, 1084682, 3014, 32851, 35865, 35865, 65703, 68717, 361560, 723120, 3014, 29838, 32852, 32852, 361560, 723120, 3014, 361559, 723120, 3014, 32851, 35865, 35865, 65702, 68716, 361560, 3014, 29837, 32851, 32851, 361560, 3014, 361561, 3014, 32851, 35865, 35865, 65703, 68717, 3014, 29838, 32852, 32852, 3014]
```

And none of those differences are palindromes, so there won't be any output for either of these two formats.

(See [my Java answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200224/52210) for an answer using format `dd-mm-yyyy` like the challenge description, which I've also used to generate the lists above.)

Comment: I found a similar solution to your Polyglot one in Golfscript - I'm going to see if I can make it work in Python next!

Comment: @Mathgeek Polyglot means it works in all languages, including Golfscript and Python. ;)

Comment: I'm aware, [I'm being intentionally dense for comedic value] ;p

Comment: Doesn't this violate a couple of the the standard loopholes like [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8094/72767) or maybe [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8245/72767)

Comment: @Xcali, we also have a consensus somewhere that proofs of "impossibility" are valid.

Comment: @Xcali _Shaggy_ is indeed correct: [Is a proof of impossibility allowed as an answer?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16172/is-a-proof-of-impossibility-allowed-as-an-answer) Although that meta question is mainly directed to challenges with no valid solutions at all, so I guess there is a fine line in this challenge where alternative formats do give proper outputs.

Answer (score 3):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 305 bytes

```
p: func[s n][at to""10 ** n + s 2]s: func[d][rejoin[p d/4 2 p d/3 2 p d/2 4]]
r: func[s][s: to""s s = reverse copy s]a: to-date[1 1 1]b:
collect[until[if r s a[keep a]a: a + 1 a/2 = 1e4]]repeat i l: length? b[repeat
j l[if all[i < j(sort s b/:i)= sort s b/:j
r t: b/:j - b/:i][print[s b/:i s b/:j"::"t]]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY6xbsMwDER3f8XBU5oiSO1mEmr0H7oSHGSbaeUKsiApAfr1Lu24qDQcJd49Msm4fMhIvESD6y0MlBGYbEGZ67p5wfGIgGdktJx3x8iUZJpdoIjxfEGLVV93bXFhrtIfjUljKysro0OSu6QsGOb4g8x27Z1GW4Qa6OXeVMPsvQyFbqE4T@6KpElL3yIRdk1Y3aeB1UkdGtFpSaLoxg7ewEv4LF/v6OnxW03YINar4A3TIc@pKLE/G/fU4f81VQnFbBVOW5spJhcKPcy7qzamLqxnWX4B)

In dd-mm-yyyy format. I'm listing the pairs only once. Currently there is no separator in the dates - I'll fix it if it's necessary.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>115 109</s>  108 bytes

Date format: `dd-mm-yyyy`.

```javascript
_=>[-1102,-1101,-2,0,2,4,5,7,9].map(y=>([,a,b,c,d]=y+11303+'',[a+b+(m='-'+c+d+'-'+d+c)+b+a,b+a+m+a+b,6556]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYpdCoMwGASPk8i3kUQbiw/xIkFKfrS0GCO1FDy9jQ87A8O@3c/t4fPavmLNcTpncz7MYIVSssFFBdFAosENGnf0Y53cxg8zcAsHj4A4moOUamVLjME68sSTYYJRoEiXI4Wq1HInR6nMo9O6G6vqDHnd8zLVS37ymZfwBw)

Comment: Well done but 31-09-9013 does not exist in the current calendar

Comment: @RegisPortalez My bad. Now fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Uses format `ddmmyyyy` for the palindrome checks like the challenge description.

### Java 8 (hard-coded), 190 bytes

```java
v->"31100113 13100131x20011002 02011020x31011013 13011031x20022002 02022020x31122113 13122131x31033013 13033031x31055013 13055031x31077013 13077031x31088013 13088031x".replace("x"," 6556\n")
```

As expected, a lot shorter than calculating it..
Outputs in the format `ddmmyyyy`.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LZDNasMwEITveYpFJxkaox@cBELzBsml0Evbg6q4RamiGFs2LiXP7o4igQTfjmYFMxczmfXl/LNYb4aBjsaFvxWRC7Htv4xt6ZRGopfYu/BNlr/e3Jmmag/1joszRBOdpRMFeqZlWh@YllIIKTVJnUDLWaVZCEVCJVBixgvg4UmQPUoVD@DhkUqVfwDwYEvrsgXIStMUBZCV7bYogKzsdkUBQGF133Ye@Tib2ROjTdNs3gOrlv0Kibrx0yNRCTalxFcUw3MJbx@mKqX8DrG91rcx1h1eog881JaH0fuqNHRf/gE)

**Explanation:**

```java
v->   // Method with empty unused parameter and String return-type
  "31100113 13100131x20011002 02011020x31011013 13011031x20022002 02022020x31122113 13122131x31033013 13033031x31055013 13055031x31077013 13077031x31088013 13088031x"
      //  Return this String
    .replace("x"," 6556\n")
      //  after we've replaced all "x" with " 6556\n"
```

### Java 10 (calculated), <s>524</s> <s>486</s> 476 bytes

```java
import java.time.*;v->{var D=LocalDate.of(1,1,1);java.util.Arrays A=null;var L=D.datesUntil(D.of(10000,1,1)).filter(d->{var s=(d+"").split("-");return p(s[2]+s[1]+s[0]);}).toArray(LocalDate[]::new);for(var a:L)for(var b:L){var x=(a+"").split("");var y=(b+"").split("");A.sort(x);A.sort(y);var d=a.until(b,java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.DAYS);if(d>0&A.equals(x,y)&p(d+""))System.out.println(a+" "+b+" "+d);}}boolean p(String s){return s.contains(new StringBuffer(s).reverse());}
```

Uses the same format as in the challenge description for the checks `ddmmyyyy`, but outputs as format `yyyy-mm-dd`.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##XVJNb9swDL33VxA@FNKSqMlujeEC3nxMewk6YAhykG25VapIrkR7MYL89oxy0naYbUkUza/Hx53s5WxXv531vnUeYUd3gXqvxLcU7u5gsrgHdICvCsoB1axyncWbysgQ4FFqe7wB0BaVb2Sl4CleAXqna6jYr3j0PCXdiRZ9T2Ahg3M/ezj20kORrVwlTSFRCdewxZReno4ldKiNyL2XQ4A8s50xafRYZYWoyTw8WzJgxeg2p2d05aLRhmph9TVByFg9SRIuQms0smSW8NQr7LyFloXN9@0kbBZxm295euIC3ZiSfZa12S6XVv3haeM8ixHlcsU/5JLkMc0hY/LfNJQlqoeMlf@pcxGoy@zwKQ0X0zojyCOkcvpFAapIijTi56t31j1bjaLIf695qhtWP8xvc6HeO2kCO0wHfttewPL1EMhTuA5F64kcY2N5kEzKca8J6iktnTNKxj6skYxeIPDjtTVBVM4ikRsYYYfL/x9d01BnAxde9coHxTjFOROpbVcaXUFAiXSM3O/J@Rp3s5X8MhUxVhwZxoUVFYucXmfjdP4L)

**Explanation:**

```java
import java.time.*;       // Import for both LocalDate
v->{                      // Method with empty unused parameter and no return-type
  var D=LocalDate.of(1,1,1);
                          //  LocalDate variable to save bytes, with date 01-01-0001
  java.util.Arrays A=null;//  Static Arrays to save bytes
  var L=D.datesUntil(D.of(10000,1,1))
                          //  Create a stream of dates in the range [01-01-0001,01-01-9999]:
        .filter(d->{      //  Filter it by:
          var s=(d+"")    //   Convert the date to a String in the format "yyyy-mm-dd"
            .split("-");  //   And split it at the "-"
      return p(s[2]+s[1]+s[0]);})
                          //   Return whether "ddmmyyyy" is a palindrome
        .toArray(LocalDate[]::new);
                          //  And convert that filtered stream to an array of LocalDates
for(var a:L)for(var b:L){ //  Nested loop over all these dates a,b:
  var x=(a+"")            //   Convert date `a` to a String,
        .split("");       //   and then into an array of characters
  var y=(b+"").split(""); //   Do the same for date `b`
  A.sort(x);A.sort(y);    //   Sort the characters in both arrays
  var d=a.until(b,java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.DAYS);
                          //   Get the difference in days between the two dates
  if(d>0                  //   If this difference is larger than 0,
                          //   (which means a is before b, and they are not the same)
     &A.equals(x,y)       //   and the two sorted character-arrays are equal,
                          //   (which means a and b are anagrams)
     &p(d+""))            //   and the difference is a palindrome:
    System.out.println(a+" "+b+" "+d);}}
                          //    Print the pair a,b and difference with trailing newline

// Separated method to check if a String is a palindrome:
boolean p(String s){      // Method with String parameter and boolean return-type
  return s.contains(      //  Return whether the input-string contains:
    new StringBuffer(s).reverse());}
                          //   The reversed input-String(Buffer)
```

Answer (score 1):

[HARCODED]

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 194 bytes

```php
<?=str_replace("x"," 6556
","31100113 13100131x20011002 02011020x31011013 13011031x20022002 02022020x31122113 13122131x31033013 13033031x31055013 13055031x31077013 13077031x31088013 13088031x");
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lcy9CsMgGIXhvVchTil0@H7QBJqQSwmhBDp0EJvBuzfH@G2Pr0fTN9U6r8v/zFs@0m//HIMv/uVdDCE@AGUmYlbH2qBcpJ2JxJE0CBXcAPemoW9EbAPcGxaxfwBs8ErVXgG9hGAF6GUcrQC9TJMVAMU/37Ve)

[WITH CAUTION]: shorter version that assumes following Kevin Cruijssen's results (I haven't verified them) that the difference in days will always be 6556:

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 223 bytes

```php
$a=date_create('0000-12-31');for(;($c=($d=clone$a->modify('+1day'))->format('dmY'))!=31129999;)if($c==strrev($c)&($e=$d->modify('+6556day')->format('dmY'))==strrev($e)&count_chars($c,1)==count_chars($e,1))echo"$c $e 6556
";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYzLCoMwEEX3/QorwSS0gUZRKGnsd3QlIRlRqEZiWvDr7dhNH3cxjztzz9RN6@U6YSVGOxOhsQGwMXpCCZmLQlKuWh@YYsRqRpy2dz8CMaIevOvbhdGDdGahnIsa/wYTGXXDDfe9LqTMzyjF@3aL6zmGAE8cecYIaOK@KFVZVm/QP@cTA55Z/xhjYzsTZsQcJV5/LECLg@18SmxCINmou1St6ws)

[FULL VERSION THAT CALCULATES WITH ALL DATES]:

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 283 bytes

```php
$a=date_create('0000-12-31');for(;($c=($d=clone$a->modify('+1day'))->format('dmY'))!=31129999;){for(;($e=$d->modify('+1day')->format('dmY'))!=31129999;)if($c==strrev($c)&$e==strrev($e)&count_chars($c,1)==count_chars($e,1)&($f=$d->diff($a)->format('%a'))==strrev($f))echo"$c $e $f
";}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY3LCsIwEEX3fkWVscmgBVNXUlO/w5WEZEILtimxCiJ@ex1FfCA4i3nfe7qqG9abjjMY7UxPOxuJixQLjkzl2VIJLHyIspBgtQSn7T60BCYrm@Bqf5Zippw5C8Ss5L/G9FK4ZsvzWC@VylccBV6eFqTB/Sj/CWt/5@pDHyOduMWUPV4jYWrDse13tjLxwOe5Qq2/VsSrVIJ/gBnLfuaDODUMfBt6RLJVmIBNgBLwo0lxHYYb)

Dates format is `dd-mm-yyyy`, pairs are displayed in one order only. formats the inputs like `dd-mm-yyyy dd-mm-yyyy n` but doesn't separate them (count 1 bytes more for a new line).

Actually times out pretty quick.. cannot even check the first result in TIO. Note that the date `31-12-9999` is never tested (loops pre-increment), but it doesn't matter because it's not a palindrome anyway..

EDIT: added hardcoded version (port of Kevin Cruijssen's) + switched to format `ddmmyyyy` (without `-`) with a new line for the other versions

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 39 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
31 9и20₂S;ǝDí«•1/K†Þ'āD•2×2ôøJº2äøŽP¶δª
```

05AB1E doesn't even have any date buitlins, so hard-coded it is. ;)
Uses and outputs in format `ddmmyyyy`. Outputs as a list of triplets.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AUsAtP9vc2FiaWX//zMxIDnQuDIw4oKCUzvHnUTDrcKr4oCiMS9L4oCgw54nxIFE4oCiMsOXMsO0w7hKwroyw6TDuMW9UMK2zrTCqv/Cu/8) (the `»` in the footer is to pretty-print them, but feel free to remove it to see the actual output).

**Explanation:**

```python
31             # Push 31
   9и          # Repeat it 9 times as list: [31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31]
     20        # Push 20
       ₂S      # Push builtin 26 as digit list: [2,6]
         ;     # Halve each: [1,3]
          ǝ    # Insert 20 at both those (0-based) indices: [31,20,31,20,31,31,31,31,31]
           D   # Duplicate this list
            í  # Reverse each: [13,"02",13,"02",13,13,13,13,13]
             « # Merge the two lists together:
               #  [31,20,31,20,31,31,31,31,31,13,"02",13,"02",13,13,13,13,13]
•1/K†Þ'āD•    '# Push compressed integer 100101021203050708
          2×   # Double this as string: "100101021203050708100101021203050708"
            2ô # Split it into parts of size 2:
               #  [10,"01","01","02",12,"03","05","07","08",10,"01","01","02",12,"03","05","07","08"]
ø              # Zip the two lists together, creating pairs:
               #  [[31,10],[20,"01"],[31,"01"],[20,"02"],[31,12],[31,"03"],...]
 J             # Join each pair together to a string: [3110,2001,3101,2002,3112,3103,...]
  º            # Mirror each: [31100113,20011002,31011013,20022002,31122113,31033013,...]
   2ä          # Split the list into two equal parts (of size 9)
     ø         # Zip/transpose it, swapping rows/columns:
               #   [[31100113,13100131],[20011002,"02011020"],[31011013,13011031],...]
      ŽP¶      # Push compressed integer 6556
         δª    # And append it to each pair to create triplets
               # (after which that list of triplets is output implicitly as result)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `•1/K†Þ'āD•` is `100101021203050708` and `ŽP¶` is `6556`.